# Conditional increment in xsl for-each loop

Tags: xml, xslt, iteration, immutability

Given the following XML format:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<items>
  <id>7</id>
  <id></id>
  <id/>
  <id>9</id>
  <id/>
</items>
```

I'd like to auto-decrement every given "id", ideally using XSLT version 1.0.

Due to the immutability of the variables in XSL, I could only come up with the following solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <items>
      <xsl:for-each select="items/id[text()]">
        <id><xsl:value-of select="."/></id>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:for-each select="items/id[not(text())]">
        <id><xsl:value-of select="-position()"/></id>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </items>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this breaks the orders of the elements.
I would prefer this resulting xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<items>
  <id>7</id>
  <id>-1</id>
  <id>-2</id>
  <id>9</id>
  <id>-3</id>
</items>
```

Is there a more proper way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xsl:number`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="id[not(normalize-space())]">
      <xsl:copy>-<xsl:number count="id[not(normalize-space())]"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGcU